# Open button on keyboard immediately sends form

Tags: html, forms, keyboard, form-submit, smartphone

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="form_send.php" method="post">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="address">address</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" tabindex="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="country">country</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="country" name="country" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="3" />
</form>
```

If the user opens Safari or other browser on his/her smartphone and fills out the text fields, he has the possibility to click on `Open`. If this button is pressed the form is immediately sent.

Is there a possibility that the user first jumps to the second text field before he can submit the form?

I tried to use `tabindex` but that doesn't helped me. I know I can make fields mandatory with PHP/Javascript, but the fields shouldn't be mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be pressing enter for the user. You can prevent this by intercepting keystrokes.

This bit of code (jQuery) will prevent forms from being submitted by pressing ENTER.

```
$('form').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

Comment: Seems to work (after including the jquery library two times). Is there a way to place the control on the next `tabindex` when pressing ENTER or open?